# Calling specific columns by header name in Query with ImportJson function in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I am using a Query combined with ImportJson function to call an api and retrieve it's data in Google Sheets. Currently I have been using the Select Col(x) method but that doesn't work when the api frequently changes around the column order.

`=QUERY(IMPORTJSONBasicAuth(URL;;;;"noInherit,noTruncate");"select Col3,Col4,Col6")`

I want the formula to retrieve the data based on specified column headers.
Headers examples:

- Content Rank
- Content ID
- Content Points

I have tried some workarounds but could not manage to make this happen unfortunately.

Could anyone help me out?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ;IMPORTJSONBasicAuth(URL;;;;"noInherit,noTruncate");
    choosecols(Σ;index(xmatch({"Content Rank"\"Content ID"\"Content Points"};chooserows(Σ;1)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be, there is no direct way to pass column header to `QUERY()` function to select columns. Fe tricks can be applied. In case of below scenario, formula will return columns for header `Test1,Test3,Test5`.

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A3:E,BYCOL(SPLIT("Test1,Test3,Test5",","),LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(x,INDEX(A2:E,1)))))
```

To adopt the above formula in your case you may give a try to the below formul

```
=LET(imp,IMPORTJSONBasicAuth(URL;;;;"noInherit,noTruncate"),
CHOOSECOLS(imp,BYCOL(SPLIT("Test1,Test3,Test5",","),LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(x,INDEX(imp,1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Comma `,` and semicolon `;` depends on regional and language settings.